# Directories cease to exist while using tmux

Tags: ssh, bash, tmux

When I connect via ssh to a terminal at work I need to keep sessions alive to run various scripts. However, I often find that the scripts fail because some directory ceases to exist in the meantime.

For example, I get errors like `sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory` after a few hours, or `The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found` if I run pip.

How do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: If you think tmux is responsible check your `~/.tmux.conf` to see if it is setting up some unusual config. In your shell `echo $PWD` should show the name of the current directory, even if it no longer exists. Perhaps the name of this dir may provide a clue.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Indeed why the downvote. This happens very regularly to me with tmux if I quit X and restart. But the directory the tmux hosted shell is in is still there,

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution: Stay out of volatile directories

Better  solution: Built good error handling in your scripts. Plenty of `if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then` blocks etc.

Comment: I simply log into my account and launch python scripts from my home directory. It looks as if it's due to tmux, because the errors never occur when I run scripts while logged via ssh. But I don't know how to debug it.